# How django and ExtJS passing data to each other by JSON?

Tags: django, json, extjs

I am new to web development, recenlty I am learning to build a webserver using django + ExtJs. but I am confusing about how to use django + ExtJS together.
   For django, it has template to display the data, the parameter passing to html files could be dict, and could send JSON. I am trying to use it as the backend of the webserver.
ExtJS, support JSON.

Then here comes myquestion:
   How to make .html files( used by django as the template layer) to accept "JSON"? It seems that  ExtJS has no ability of sending json data through socket or other IPC.
   It seems that ExtJS has the ability to use AJAX to "post" the data to backend, however, I am not sure how the .html could get data from backend using JSON? I downloaded ExtJS the 4.2.1 version, and find some examples in the files, however, it only give some example to get data from "json files".
   Can someone give me an example or show me which aspect I should learn or explain its mechanism briefly?

Comment: This question is too confused to answer. "html" files don't "accept" anything, they are just templates or static pages.

Comment: Daniel: it seemed to me that I could understand the underlying confusion, and hopefully I helped the OP, but I agree that the question is unclear and may not be of value for others. I'm not sure what's the policy about such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>This is done not at template layer, but at view level. You should write a **view function** in Python and assign it to some URL address. In that view function, you can access JSON data sent by ExtJS and process it how you wish.</s>

I totally misread your question, here's the updated answer:

- On Django side, you should write a view function, which would return JSON response, and assign that view to some URL address. (See [How to write a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view) in Django documentation, if you're new to this.)
- On ExtJS side, you should make an Ajax request to that URL, and provide `success` callback function that will be able to access the output of Django view function. (Seems like Ajax requests in ExtJS are usually done using [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/ajax.html).)

Comment: thanks very much. I am not sure if I make myself clear. My point is after ExtJS receive data from django or whatever could send JSON, (I didn't want the JSON object passing as .html parameter in the URL), besides passing the parameter(especially JSON) by the URL's "?=para1=1&para2=2.."ways, is there other ways could receie JSON more elegant?

Comment: Hmm, it still is not clear to me: are you talking about receiving JSON in Django, or in ExtJS?

Comment: Instead of using GET parameters (?param=x), you can place your data as JSON in request body, if you're sending data from ExtJS to Django.